# Add vertical lines to ggplot2 bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am doing some research on non-defaulters and defaulters with regards to banking. In that context I am plotting their distributions relative to some score in a bar plot. The higher the score, the better the credit rating.

Since the number of defaults is very limited compared to the number of non-defaults plotting the defaults and non-defaults on the same bar plot is not very giving as you hardly can see the defaults. I then make a second bar plot based on the defaulters' scores only, but on the same interval scale as the full bar plot of both the scores of the defaulters and non-defaulters. I would then like to add vertical lines to the first bar plot indicating where the highest defaulter score is located and the lowest defaulter score is located. That is to get a view of where the distribution of the defaulters fit into that of the overall distribution of both defaulters and non-defaulters.

Below is the code I am using replaced with (seeded) random data instead.

```
library(ggplot2)

#NDS represents non-defaults and DS defaults on the same scale
#although here being just some random normals for the sake of simplicity.
set.seed(10)
NDS<-rnorm(10000,sd=1)-2
DS<-rnorm(100,sd=2)-5

#Cutoffs are constructed such that intervals of size 0.3 
#contain all values of NDS & DS
minCutoff<--9.3
maxCutoff<-2.1

#Generate the actual interval "bins"
NDS_CUT<-cut(NDS,breaks=seq(minCutoff, maxCutoff, by = 0.3))
DS_CUT<-cut(DS,breaks=seq(minCutoff, maxCutoff, by = 0.3))

#Manually generate where to put the vertical lines for min(DS) and max(DS)
minDS_bar<-levels(cut(NDS,breaks=seq(minCutoff, maxCutoff, by = 0.3)))[1]
maxDS_bar<-levels(cut(NDS,breaks=seq(minCutoff, maxCutoff, by = 0.3)))[32]

#Generate data frame - seems stupid, but makes sense
#when the "real" data is used :-)
NDSdataframe<-cbind(as.data.frame(NDS_CUT),rep(factor("State-1"),length(NDS_CUT)))
colnames(NDSdataframe)<-c("Score","Action")
DSdataframe<-cbind(as.data.frame(DS_CUT),rep(factor("State-2"),length(DS_CUT)))
colnames(DSdataframe)<-c("Score","Action")
fulldataframe<-rbind(NDSdataframe,DSdataframe)
attach(fulldataframe)

#Plot the full distribution of NDS & DS
# with geom_vline(xintercept = minDS_bar) + geom_vline(xintercept = maxDS_bar)
# that unfortunately does not show :-(
fullplot<-ggplot(fulldataframe, aes(Score, fill=factor(Action,levels=c("State-2","State-1")))) +     geom_bar(position="stack") + opts(axis.text.x = theme_text(angle = 45))  + opts    (legend.position = "none")    + xlab("Scoreinterval") + ylab("Antal pr. interval") + geom_vline(xintercept = minDS_bar) + geom_vline(xintercept = maxDS_bar) 

#Generate dataframe for DS only
#It might seem stupid, but again makes sense
#when using the original data :-)
DSdataframe2<-cbind(as.data.frame(DS_CUT),rep(factor("State-2"),length(DS_CUT)))
colnames(DSdataframe2)<-c("theScore","theAction")

#Calucate max number of observations to adjust bar plot of DS only
myMax<-max(table(DSdataframe2))+1
attach(DSdataframe2)

#Generate bar plot of DS only
subplot<-ggplot(fulldataframe, aes(theScore, fill=factor(theAction))) + geom_bar        (position="stack") + opts(axis.text.x = theme_text(angle = 45))  + opts(legend.position = "none") +     ylim(0, myMax) + xlab("Scoreinterval") + ylab("Antal pr. interval")

#plot on a grid
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(2, 1)))
vplayout <- function(x, y)
viewport(layout.pos.row = x, layout.pos.col = y)
print(fullplot, vp = vplayout(1, 1))
print(subplot, vp = vplayout(2, 1))

#detach dataframes
detach(DSdataframe2)
detach(fulldataframe)
```

Furthermore, if anybody has an idea of how I can align the to plot so that correct intervals are just below/above each other on the grid plot

Hope somebody is able to help!

Thanks in advance,

Christian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap `aes` around the `xintercept` in the `geom_vline` layer:

```
... + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = minDS_bar)) + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = maxDS_bar))
```

Comment: Thanks! Works brillianty! Do you have an idea on how to align the two plots on the grid? That is, such that interval X is below interval X, interval Y below interval Y on the two plots? I tried aligning using the ggExtra package [link]http://code.google.com/p/ggextra/ however that did not solve the issue. Furthermore I haved tried to see if I could force the width of the y-axises of the two plots to be the same, but without luck.

Comment: @Christian - glad it worked for you! I'm not sure I follow your follow up question. It's probably worth making a new question with a reproducible example. You'll get more foot traffic to your question that way and people who come searching for similar answers in the future will have a question to find instead of looking in the comments of other answers. I unfortunately don't have much experience with `ggextra` either...

Comment: Thanks! The answer was given by @Andrie. I'm new to Stack Overflow so I did not know whether it was inappropiate to make a new question regarding "literally" the same question. At least, I guess you get my point :-)

Answer (score 1):

Question 1:

Since you provide the vertical lines as data, you have to map the aesthetics first, using aes()

```
fullplot <-ggplot(
        fulldataframe, 
        aes(Score, fill=factor(Action,levels=c("State-2","State-1")))) +     
        geom_bar(position="stack") + 
        opts(axis.text.x = theme_text(angle = 45))  + 
        opts    (legend.position = "none")    + 
        xlab("Scoreinterval") + 
        ylab("Antal pr. interval") + 
        geom_vline(aes(xintercept = minDS_bar)) + 
        geom_vline(aes(xintercept = maxDS_bar))
```

Second question:

To align the plots, you can use the align.plots() function in package ggExtra

```
install.packages("dichromat")
install.packages("ggExtra", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
library(ggExtra)

ggExtra::align.plots(fullplot, subplot)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Andrie! I must have misused the ggExtra package initially!

Comment: Can you redesign the plot somehow so you don't need score intervals plotted on an angle? Haven't dug into the code above, but for binned continuous data can't you just plot with numeric labels (rather than bin definitions)?